# VirtualAllocEx throws ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

OpenProcess is not returning NULL and returns what seems to be a valid handle. I'm running SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE enabled so access level should be fine. Any help?

```cpp
            void* processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, processID);
            printf("%p\n", processHandle);

            void* DLLPATH = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, 0, (strlen(dllPATH) + 2), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
            printf("%p\n", DLLPATH);
```

This all looks fine but VirtualAllocEx is throwing an invalid handle error. Any help lads? Cheers for the response!

EDIT: I debugged the program that I was looking into and found that it was trying to close the handle that I had created similar to an anticheat. That's what was causing the invalid handle error (From what I can tell).

Comment: I''m unable to replicate this when I attempt to run this code on Windows 10 x64 v1903, build 18362.836. I'm doing this to a user-mode application that doesn't have any weird protection set on it. Can you share more details as to what process you're trying to do this to, and if there might be any protection such as an antivirus or anti-cheat module involved?

Comment: I'm trying to inject a dll into a process known as Razer Synapse Service.exe which may have some sort of protection on it since it shows up as red in process explorer and to view a dll snapshot of it i have to run Process Explorer as Administrator (Which btw I ran the injector itself as admin and had SE_DEBUG_PRIVALEGE on). Still no luck. If I had to guess it's a driver of some sorts. But one weird thing is when I copy the file over to another location like desktop, i can debug with x64dbg and do stuff. I'm guessing it has some sort of signature that is protecting it.

Comment: I normally couldn't debug it with x64dbg btw.

Comment: First off, `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is way too much privileges to request. You don't need that many privileges to inject a DLL. Second, you did not show the code where you validate that `VirtualAllocEx()` is reporting `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, there is no error handling in the code you have shown, so how do you know it is actually doing that? For all we can tell, the `printf()` could be resetting the error code before you retrieve it. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your real code.

Comment: According to my copy of Process Explorer, light red just means it's an NT service.

Comment: Remy Lebeau - I checked it before with GetLastError and it returned 6 which is invalid handle. I removed that print part afterwards. VirtualAllocEx returning 0 with GetLastError returning 6. just because PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS is too much doesn't mean it is causing the issue. I asked for information on why it could not be working. You responded with code critique.

Comment: nanofarad - Yeah that's what I thought. Is there any way of debugging that or and way to open a process handle?

Answer (score 0):

Session 0 isolation. It's a service, and you are not actually allowed to access a process from session 0 from an interactive session, and vice versa.

The clean way? Rip it out of service context, or go debugging from service context yourself.

The ugly way? Go an use your debug privileges to open `winlogon.exe`, read it's security token and impersonate it. That process has some undocumented, hidden privileges which allow it to disregard session 0 isolation.

Comment: I looked into the debugger for the process and found something similar to an anticheat where it calls NtQuerySystemInformationEx to grab a list of handles and NtQueryObject to check if that handle is opened to that process, and if so, it's closing it - that's from what I can tell causing the invalid handle error code. Appreciate the response though man!